Is there a way to make one top shell always on top of another top shell?
There are two Shells A and B created using the SWT.ON_TOP style, is there a way to make A always on top of B?

If A has B as its parent it should stay on top of B

In my actual scenario, B could have been created later, and B would not be the parent of A, because the Shell cannot reset the parent on Windows. : (

Shell.moveAbove(null) will bring a shell to the front, I don't know if it will stay there.

The timing of using the moveAbove method is an issue. As encountered here[https://stackoverflow.com/q/79100547/19473836], the first state is reached by the moveAbove method, but the second state occurs without seemingly detecting any events, don't know when to call moveAbove.
