How to listen for clicks on the Shell title bar ？
There are two SWT.ON_TOP style Shells as follows, A is above B and B is active.
state 1

Clicking on the title bar of B puts B on top of A. This does not detect any Activate, Deactivate or MouseDown events, but the interface does change. Is there any way for me to know this action by the user?
state 2

test code:
public class ShellTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shell shellA = new Shell( SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP ) ;
        shellA.setSize( 300, 300 ) ;
        shellA.setText( "A" ) ;
        
        Shell shellB = new Shell( SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP ) ;
        shellB.setSize( 300, 300 ) ;
        shellB.setText( "B" ) ;
        
        shellB.addListener( SWT.Activate, e -> {
            if ( shellA != null && !shellA.isDisposed() ) {
                shellA.moveAbove( null ) ;
            }
        } ) ;
        
        Display display = shellB.getDisplay() ;
        display.addFilter( SWT.Activate, e -> System.out.println( e ) ) ;
        display.addFilter( SWT.Deactivate, e -> System.out.println( e ) ) ;

        
        shellA.open() ;
        shellB.open() ;
        
        while ( !shellA.isDisposed() && !shellB.isDisposed() ) {
            if ( !display.readAndDispatch() ) {
                display.sleep() ;
            }
        }
        display.dispose() ;
    }
    
}

First click on the content area of B to reach state 1, and then click on the title bar of B to reach state 2.

Testing here I get Activate/Deactivate events for the shells

I updated the test code and in the second click on the B title bar, there is no Activate/Deactivate event.

I tested it on macOS and it didn't. In state 1, A is Deactivate and B is Activate, and in state 2, there is no change in the active state of either of them, so why would there be an Activate/Deactivate event?

Sorry I misunderstood. Why would you expect any event clicking on the same window. "state1" and "state 2" are the same state. I get activate/deactivate events when clicking on the other window. You aren't going to get separate events for clicking on the title.

The ultimate goal is for A to always be above B. But the two shells in the example, both of which are ON_TOP style and have no hierarchical relationship, don't seem to be able to do anything when it comes to the state 2 scenario.
